# No result rowset is associated with the execution of this query

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating an Execute SQL task in SSIS 2016 which calls an insert stored procedure. I am trying to return the id of the newly created row in the output parameter but facing the following error.

> No result rowset is associated with the execution of this query

I had set the SQL Server Profiler on to see what was generated and it was as follows

```
declare @p4 int
set @p4=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'Exec [dbo].[InsertPkgAudit] @P1,@P2',N'@P1 varchar(16),@P2 int OUTPUT','CoreReferenceETL',@p4 output
select @p4
```

If I execute the following it manually it works

```
DECLARE @auditId INT;
EXEC [dbo].[InsertPkgAudit] @packageName = 'CoreReferenceETL', @auditId = @auditId OUTPUT;
PRINT @auditId;
```

So it is clear that the stored procedure is fine but some problem with the way its called in SSIS. Could somebody help ?

The Execute SQL task contains the following statement

```
Exec [dbo].[InsertPkgAudit] @packageName =?, @auditId = ?
```

The parameter mapping is as follows

[image]

The result pane is as follows

[image]

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[InsertPkgAudit]
    @packageName varchar(100),
    @auditId int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PkgAudit] ([PackageName], [StartTime])
    VALUES (@packageName, GETDATE());

    SET @auditId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

The table structure is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have told SSIS that your procedure returns a result set.   But it doesn't.   It populates an OUTPUT parameter instead.

You can either change your proc to return a resultset, or you can modify the Execute task and

1. Specify No Result Set
2. Change the query to this:

```
`Exec [dbo].[InsertPkgAudit] @packageName =?, @auditId = ? OUTPUT`
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and while looking for some sort of solution I came across this old post. I wasn't able to find the solution online but, here is how I resolved my issue. I hope this helps folks in the future.

If you really need to get the data passed via RowSet, you will need to select as 
'ColumnName'.

```
Declare @fname varchar(50)
Declare @lname varchar(50)

set @fname ='John'
set @lname= 'Doe'

select @fname, @lname--without column name

select @fname as 'firstName', @lname as 'LastName'--with column name
```

Here is how they would show up in the results.

[image]

You can now map the result to proper variable.